# Getting a NullReferenceException error while rendering a multilist field value in Sitecore 8.2

Tags: data-binding, sitecore, carousel

I am trying to create a carousel in Sitecore 8.2. I have created a carousel item with the Image and Text fields and these carousel items are mapped to `Multilist`. I am getting a null reference error while rendering the multilist items in Visual Studio.

My View code:

```html
<div id="home-carousel" class="jcarousel-wrapper">
<a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next">&rsaquo;</a>

<div class="jcarousel carousel-stage">
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCarousel" ItemType="Sitecore.Data.Items.Item" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
<ul class="carousel">
</HeaderTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
<li>
<sc:Image Field="Carousel Image" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" />
<sc:Text Field="Carousel Text" Item="<%# Container.DataItem %>" runat="server" />
</li>
</ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
</ul>
</FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>
</div>
```

My back-end code:

```
   public partial class carousel : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var sublayout = Parent as Sublayout;
            var datasource = sublayout.DataSource;
            Item Carousel = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(datasource);
            Item[] item = Carousel.Children.ToArray();
            rptCarousel.DataSource = item;
            rptCarousel.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: try Item[] item = Carousel.Children.where(i=>i!=null).ToArray(); and better to ask this on https://sitecore.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not fetching items from multilist, you are trying to bind children of that datasource item.

So make sure you have published the node correctly and their template.

Make sure datasource is the node under which all the carousel items are placed.

If you want to render items by multilist then you need to correct your code.

```
public partial class carousel : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var sublayout = Parent as Sublayout;
            var datasource = sublayout.DataSource;
            Item Carousel = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(datasource);
            MultilistField field = Carousel.Field["Multilist field Name"];
             if (field != null)
              {
                rptCarousel.DataSource = field.GetItems().ToList();
                rptCarousel.DataBind();
              }
        }
    }
```